# AWS S3 copyObject 403 access denied

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I called s3 api by copyObject.
But, i got the 403 error for access denied.

I have configured it as follows.

IAM + CORS settings

IAM is S3FullAccess.

CORS is allowed.

```
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "PUT",
            "POST",
            "DELETE"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "http://localhost:3002"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": []
    }
]
```

I don't know what I am missing.

code:

```js
import AWS from 'aws-sdk';

AWS.config.update({
  accessKeyId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
  secretAccessKey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
})

bucket = new AWS.S3({
  params: { Bucket: 'bucket' },
  region: 'ap-northeast-2',
});

const params = {
  Bucket: 'bucket',
  CopySource: `advertisement_${i}.png`,
  Key: `advertisement_${i}_old.png`,
};

await this.bucket.copyObject(params)
  .send((err => {
    if (err) {
      alert(err);
    } else {
      console.log(`advertisement_${i} is copied`);
    }
  }));
```

Comment: Does it work if you use those same credentials with the AWS CLI to copy the object? I'm also a little suspicious of the `AllowedOrigins` in your CORS policy -- referencing `localhost:3002` does not make any sense for Amazon S3, which operates outside of your own server.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I execute on aws cli. But, same issue.

Comment: Given that the AWS CLI failed to copy the object, it suggests that either the object does not exist or you do not have permission to copy the object. If the AWS CLI cannot copy the object, then the fault is not in your code.